# How to check if message from telegram channel is image Python

Tags: python, image, variables, opencv, telethon

I need to check if last message from channel is image. If message include image I need to save that image as variable for later usage. (In this situation tesseract.image_to_string). I have this code but it isn't working.

```
async def get_mess():
    limit = 1
    global new
    global img

    async for message in client.iter_messages('SAMPLE CHANNEL', limit):
        if message.text is not None:
            new = message.text
        if message.photo in not None:
            img = message.photo
        return message
client.loop.run_until_complete(get_mess())
cv2.imshow('Image', img)
```

When I use this code it's not working because I can see my last message is image only and I still can't use it. I think the problem will be in saving image as variable. Anyone who can help me?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to get the message using [`get_messages()`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html?highlight=get_messages#telethon.client.messages.MessageMethods.get_messages) so you can omit the limit paramater. Now check if the message contains an image, then you can store the media into a variable to later usage or even download it.

```
messages = await client.get_messages('YOUR_CHAT')
if messages[0].photo: # check if the message contains an image
    await messages[0].download_media('test.png') # to download the image
    image = messages[0].media # to store the image to later usage
```

Another version using [`iter_messages()`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html?highlight=iter_messages#telethon.client.messages.MessageMethods.iter_messages) instead.

```
async for message in client.iter_messages('YOUR_CHAT', limit=1):
    if message.photo:
        await message.download_media('test.png') # to download the image
        img = message.media # to store the image to later usage
```

Comment: And If I want to use iter_messages, how should I do it than?

Comment: @Kurina11 improved the answer.

Comment: Worth noting that `if message.photo`, the media should always be a `.jpg`, not a `.png` (and the extension can be left out so Telethon infers it; the path is returned).